# Filling a DataGrid with selfmade arraylist

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a generic converter which reads any file you throw in it which "maps" it's data and gives it like this:

I got 3 classes:
DataValue, which has a value, row, and column property.
DataArray, which is a list of DataValues.
DataArrayList, which is a list of DataArrays.

I try to use put it in a datagrid with non pre-setup columns, since it should be able to read Anything.

Here's some code:

```
public void FillRows(DataArrayList arrayList)
    {
        DataArray headers = arrayList.First();
        AddColumns(headers);

        DataList = new List<DataArray>();
        lijstitems = new List<DataValue>();


        foreach (DataArray dataArrays in arrayList)
        {
            DataList.Add(new DataArray { datavalues = dataArrays.datavalues });
        }
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

Now this gives me the general name of the arrays, as a test i tried to display it in textboxes. Now i wonder how i would get a setup which displays each DataValue as a new column.

```
 private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataArray array = (DataArray)DataGrid.SelectedItem;
        var arraychar = array.datavalues.ToArray();

            textBox1.Text = arraychar[0].value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = arraychar[1].value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = arraychar[2].value.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = arraychar[3].value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = arraychar[4].value.ToString();            
    }
```

This displays the correct values i put in.

Answer (score 0):

Define a column per value you want to display in the `DataGrid`:

```
DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = new Binding("[0]") });
DataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = new Binding("[1]") });
DataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = new Binding("[2]") });
DataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = new Binding("[3]") });
DataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = new Binding("[4]") });
```